# website url's with step=1/2/3/4?

Tags: php, url

I see this alot appended to the url of a website, and when the step changes so does the page content. can anyone explain this to me in php.

I do not understand how it works.

Comment: If you are referring to "pretty" urls, it's done using `mod_rewrite` or similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432324/mod-rewrite-prefix-problem

Comment: Can you please rephrase the question to something more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers of the step are `$_GET` variables. For example if your link is www.yourdomain.com/index.php?step=3 you can fetch this step by writing (in index.php):

```
<?php
    $step = 0;
    if (isset($_GET['step']))
         $step = $_GET['step'];
?>
```

This declares a variable named `$step` and assigns the value from your URL to it (if any is set, else it's just **0**).

You can then use this step variable value to show a specific page to your user. For example by fetching data on the flow from a database.

If you wan to transform this url:

> www.yourdomain.com/index.php?step=3

into something nicer like

```
www.yourdomain.com/step/3
```

you will have to make use of a `.htaccess` file. They allow you to rewrite URL's, but as that can be pretty complicated I advise you to look around on the internet for more information about them. Such as [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html).

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you, please feel free to tick it as "correct" by clicking the big V next to the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is url rewriting.

You can do that via a .htaccess file with RewriteRule.
For exemple you can transform a url like http://example.com/a/b into something like http://example.com/script.php?arg1=a&arg2=b.

Answer (score 0):

Often there is some magic URL rewriting happening behind the scenes.
This mostly just does something like this (taking your example):
request url: www.example.com/1/2/3/4
rewritten url: www.example.com/handler.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4

So basically you are (often) not browsing any directories, the url YOU see is just to make it a little bit more attractive than what the SERVER sees.